# Character insight: What is it like to lose a child?

Tags: characters

I'm writing a short story and I find a character is more compelling if I ask those that have been through similar experiences what said experience was like.  I need to know what it feels like to lose a child. This includes the first couple hours, weeks, and even years later.  I want to do this character justice. Where can I find information on this?

Comment: My experience is that it is something I do not wish to share over a public forum. This is also a "What to Write" question and, as such, off topic on this Stack Exchange.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers SE! As it is, your question is off-topic. Learn more about Writers SE by reading a short presentation of the site [there](https://writers.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: What age child? I think there are huge differences before and after the child is a person. In what time period? Medieval culture was very different to modern and it impacted things like loss

Comment: Like Thomo, I would say that it is not necessarily something to talk about over this forum. There are, however, fora where loss of a child is discussed in a support format. By no means should you contribute on such sites (For god's sake do not tell people you want to research them!) but you might lurk and have an inkling of the enormity of it. I will also say that I see many books where loss of a child is not done correctly and it is infuriating.

Comment: As others have stated, this is not the medium for this kind of discussion. This is a bit open ended for one and leaves a discussion rather than an objective answer. Everyone deals with such events in their own ways and if you want to write about this, you are better politely asking if anyone you know have experienced this or as others said, stalk forums to strictly read the comments. As with any serious topic such as this, it's probably best to avoid unless you experienced it yourself or else you could portray it wrongly.

Comment: There are a number of insightful answers to this question on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-it-like-to-lose-a-child).

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer the original question, so I've edited it into one I can.

Entering "what is it like to lose a child?" into your preferred search engine will take you to many resources. The advantage of using these over asking contributors to a forum for their experiences is that the people you'll find are those who want to talk about their experiences - it's far too personal a question to ask on a forum that isn't specifically about this.

When researching a subject about which people are going to have very strong emotions, sympathy and empathy are essential.

High on the list of pages found by my search was this : https://www.mindbodygreen.com/0-17928/what-i-wish-more-people-understood-about-losing-a-child.html. It looks like it's a good place to start - it not only gives insight into some of the feelings people have, but also gives good guidance about how to approach people when researching something this personal.